# Why is my component not receiving data from another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I have React Components:**

***My account.jsx***

```
import "./myAccount.sass";
import { auth } from "../../firebaseConfig";
import {
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-auth.js";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Hotel } from "../Hotel/Hotel";

function MyAccount(props) {
  const { isauth } = props;
  const { hotels = [] } = props;
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState([]);

  function logout() {
    signOut(auth);
    isauth(false);
    console.log("Successful logout");
  }

  function userInfo() {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log(`user info: ${user.email}"`);
      setUserEmail(user.email);
    });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    userInfo();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Hi, {userEmail}</h3>
      <button onClick={logout}>Logout...</button>
      <h4>Your reviews:</h4>
      <hr />
      <div className="Hotels">
        {hotels.map((hotel, id) => (
          <Hotel key={id} {...hotel} filter={true} user={userEmail} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyAccount;
```

***Hotels.jsx***

```
import starsMap from "../../starsMap";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./hotel.sass";

function Hotel(props, filter = false, user = null) {
  const { name, img, localization, stars, review, author } = props;
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState(user);
  if (filter) {
    console.log(author, userEmail);
    if (author === user) {
      return (
        <div className="Hotel_card">
          <h2 className="Hotel_card-name">{name}</h2>
          <div className="Hotel_card_wrapper">
            <img className="Hotel_card-img" src={img} alt="hotel_img" />
            <h3 className="Hotel_card-localization">
              {/* Lat:{localization._lat}
              Long:{localization._lat} */}
              <button>Show on map</button>
            </h3>
            {starsMap.get(stars)}
          </div>
          <p className="Hotel_card-review">{review}</p>
          <h5 className="Hotel_card-author">Wroten by {author}</h5>
        </div>
      );
    }
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="Hotel_card">
        <h2 className="Hotel_card-name">{name}</h2>
        <div className="Hotel_card_wrapper">
          <img className="Hotel_card-img" src={img} alt="hotel_img" />
          <h3 className="Hotel_card-localization">
            {/* Lat:{localization._lat}
            Long:{localization._lat} */}
            <button>Show on map</button>
          </h3>
          {starsMap.get(stars)}
        </div>
        <p className="Hotel_card-review">{review}</p>
        <h5 className="Hotel_card-author">Wroten by {author}</h5>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export { Hotel };
```

**The MyAccount.jsx component passes two attributes to the Hotels.jsx component - filter={true} user={userEmail}.
Hotels.jsx only sees filter={true}, user remains null for it.
Question - why doesn't Hotels.jsx see the user={userEmail} passed to it?**

*If you look at the state userEmail in MyAccount.jsx, then the desired value is found this way, but it is lost at the moment it is transferred to Hotels.jsx*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are using an intermediate `useState` in the `Hotel.jsx` file and you are not receiving correctly the props

`const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState(user);`

remove that line (it seems that you are not using it anyway) and change in the `Hotels.jsx` component the prop `user` to `userEmail`:

`function Hotel({filter = false, userEmail = null, ...props})`

Answer (score 0):

A React Functional Component, is a `function` that returns some JSX code. When you write it like:

```
<Hotel key={id} {...hotel} filter={true} user={userEmail} />
```

This is JSX, and this code gets converted to React first class API:

```
React.createElement(
  Hotel,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

`props` are `filter`, `user` and whatever comes out of `{...hotel}`.

The `React.createElement` just takes `props` and `children` ( if at all ), and passes an object to your `Hotel` function with them all inside, remember that `props` is an object:

```
Hotel(props)
```

Being an object, when you want to recall your props from within your Component, you have two possible ways:

```
function Hotel (props) {
  console.log(props.filter, props.user)
}
```

or through destructuring them directly when declaring them:

```
function Hotel ({filter, user}) {
  console.log(filter, user)
}
```

If you are passing other props that you don't want to name directly:

```
function Hotel ({filter, user, ...props}) {
  console.log(filter, user, props)
}
```